# IE/Firefox style update via javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, internet-explorer-8, styles

I have a program that takes a name from an auto-complete and sends it to a javascript function that dynamically creates a Label with a button inside it.  When I try to use the DOM methods to set style properties, it doesn't work in Firefox/IE 7, but it does in IE 8/Chrome.
Here is the function,

```
function fnCreate(client) {
                    var newLbl = document.createElement("label");
                    var newBtn = document.createElement("input");
                    var hidden = document.getElementById("count");
                    var val = parseInt(hidden.value) + 1;
                    hidden.setAttribute("value", val);
                    newLbl.setAttribute("id", "lbl" + client + val);
                    newBtn.setAttribute("id", "btn" + client + val);
                    newBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
                    newBtn.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #6D84B4; background-image: url('X.png'); vertical-align: middle; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: center; height: 14px;border-style: none;  border-width: 0px; ");
                    newLbl.innerHTML = client;
                    newLbl.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #6084B4; color: #FFFFFF");
                    newBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "fnDelete('" + client + val + "')");
                    newLbl.appendChild(newBtn);
                    myData.appendChild(newLbl);
```

The input parameter "client" is the name.  It should append the button to the label, then append the label to myData, which is a div inside of a table.

```
<label id="lblDimitris1" style="">
```

This is the markup for IE8 after the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution in my opinion is to actually create 2 classes, which will improve maintainability. You'd have css classes looking something like this

```
.button1 {
    background-color: #6D84B4; 
    background-image: url('X.png'); 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    text-align: center; 
    height: 14px;
    border: 0; 
}

.label1 {
    background-color: #6084B4; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

In your JavaScript you'd now do something like this

```
newBtn.className = 'button1';
newLbl.className = 'label1';
```

Much easier to read and maintain.

The full code would be the following

```
function fnCreate(client) {
    var newLbl = document.createElement('label');
    var newBtn = document.createElement('input');
    var hidden = document.getElementById('count');

    var val = parseInt(hidden.value) + 1;

    hidden.value = val;
    newLbl.id = 'lbl' + client + val;
    newBtn.id = 'btn' + client + val;
    newBtn.type = 'button';
    newBtn.className = 'button1';
    newBtn.onclick = fnDelete(client + val);
    newLbl.innerHTML = client;
    newLbl.className = 'label1'

   newLbl.appendChild(newBtn);
   myData.appendChild(newLbl);
}
```

Comment: This worked mucb better. I was having troubles setting backgroundImage in IE8 and this fixed that too. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function fnCreate(client) {
  var newLbl = document.createElement('label');
  var newBtn = document.createElement('input');
  var hidden = document.getElementById('count');

  var val = parseInt(hidden.value) + 1;

  hidden.style.value = val;
  newLbl.style.id = 'lbl' + client + val;
  newBtn.style.id = 'btn' + client + val;
  newBtn.type = 'button';
  newBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#6D84B4';
  newBtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url(X.png)';
  newBtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
  newBtn.style.verticalAlign = 'middle';
  newBtn.style.textAlign = 'center';
  newBtn.style.height = '14px';
  newBtn.style.border: '0px';
  newBtn.onclick = fnDelete(client + val);
  newLbl.innerHTML = client;
  newLbl.style.backgroundColor = '#6084Bd';
  newLbl.style.color = '#FFFFFF';

  newLbl.appendChild(newBtn);
  myData.appendChild(newLbl);
```

}

setAttribute isn't cross-browser compliant. There are some things I'm not 100% sure about. If either your client or val variables are typecast as numbers, the parameter concatenation in your onclick fnDelete() function should work, but this depends on you. Also not sure if you can set the type of an element like this but if your above code worked on certain browsers, this should as well.

Comment: Yeah, setAttribute caused more problems than it helped.  I decided to use some custom css classes for these controls and it turned out much better. Directly setting the css seems to be the way to go :)